# How to open named pipe when process is started using uri scheme

Tags: c, winapi, pipe, url-scheme

I am developing a uri scheme registering library in C. I need to redirect the second call of the application to the first one so that only one is opened at a time. I decided to use windows named pipes for that. When I start the second instance like `start testuri://example` it works fine and the first instance receives the value `testuri://example`. However, when I start it like `explorer testuri://example` it fails to open the pipe to write.

This is my code for pipes (it is a wrapper for the winapi since I want the code to be cross platform and a Linux version also exists)

```
#include <windows.h>
#define READONLY GENERIC_READ
#define WRITEONLY GENERIC_WRITE
#define READWRITE GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ
#define CREATE_EXCLUSIVE CREATE_NEW
#define CREATE CREATE_ALWAYS

typedef struct file_desc {
    char* name;
    HANDLE hPipe;
    int isReadPipe;
} file_desc;

void pipe_create(file_desc* pipe, const char* name) {
    pipe->name = (char*) malloc(strlen(name) + 10);
    memcpy(pipe->name, "\\\\.\\pipe\\", 10);
    strcat(pipe->name, name);
    pipe->hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        TEXT(pipe->name),
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        1024 * 16,
        1024 * 16,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL
    );
}

int pipe_open(file_desc* pipe, int mode) {
    if (mode == READONLY) {
        pipe->isReadPipe = TRUE;
        return ConnectNamedPipe(pipe->hPipe, NULL);
    } return file_open(pipe,  pipe->name, mode, 1);
}

void pipe_close(file_desc* pipe) {
    if (pipe->isReadPipe) {
        DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe->hPipe);
    } else file_close(pipe);
}

int file_open(file_desc* pipe, const char* name, int mode, int lock) {
    if (!lock) pipe->hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT(name), mode,  FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
    else pipe->hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT(name), mode,  0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
    return pipe->hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

char* file_read(file_desc* pipe, char buf[], unsigned int size) {
    DWORD dwRead;
    ReadFile(pipe->hPipe, buf, size, &dwRead, NULL);
}

void file_write(file_desc* pipe, const char* str) {
    DWORD dwWritten;
    WriteFile(pipe->hPipe,str, strlen(str) + 1, &dwWritten, NULL);
}

void file_close(file_desc* pipe) {
    CloseHandle(pipe->hPipe);
}
```

The way I create the pipes is something like this

```
file_desc* pipe;
pipe_create(pipe, "mypipe");

if (firstInstance) {
    pipe_open(pipe, READONLY);
    char buf[200];
    file_read(pipe, buf, 200); 
    pipe_close(pipe);
} else {
    pipe_open(pipe, WRITEONLY);
    file_write(pipe, "test");
    pipe_close(pipe);
}
```

Full code is at https://github.com/germaniuss/libschemehandler just create an obj folder and execute make in MinGW. Then run myapp.exe

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

I tried looking at the error code at it returned error 5, access is denied. I found the problem. When opening the first instance I did that with elevated privileges, however, when opening an app using `explorer testuri://example` a new terminal window without elevated privileges pops up. This causes a problem since the pipe was created as administrator and is being accessed without.

I looked for info on this topic and found this forum exchange https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?548311-RESOLVED-Writing-to-a-named-pipe-coming-from-a-service-(session-0)-without-admin-rights which was exactly what I needed. I just needed to create an all access security descriptor for the named pipe.

I feel like the fact that the pipe is created by default as with admin only access should be more clearly stated, since it says full access is granted by default

> A pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure that specifies a security
> descriptor for the new named pipe and determines whether child
> processes can inherit the returned handle. If lpSecurityAttributes is
> NULL, the named pipe gets a default security descriptor and the handle
> cannot be inherited. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a
> named pipe grant full control to the LocalSystem account,
> administrators, and the creator owner. They also grant read access to
> members of the Everyone group and the anonymous account.

Source [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea)

In the end my pipe_open functions ended up like so

```
void pipe_create(file_desc* pipe, const char* name) {

    // all access secutrity descriptor
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = NULL;
    BYTE  sd[SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH];
    psd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)sd;
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(psd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(psd, TRUE, (PACL)NULL, FALSE);
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {sizeof(sa), psd, FALSE};

    pipe->name = (char*) malloc(strlen(name) + 10);
    memcpy(pipe->name, "\\\\.\\pipe\\", 10);
    strcat(pipe->name, name);
    pipe->hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        TEXT(pipe->name),
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        1024 * 16,
        1024 * 16,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        &sa
    );
}
```